# How to use CNN model to detect object recognized by YOLO

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

Let start by saying that i have 2 pre-trained models (in hdf5 files):

The first model is a YOLO-based model, trained on dataset A, which is used to locate human in any images (note that: a trained images o this model may contain many people inside)

The second model is a CNN model which is used to detect gender of a person (male or female) based on the image which only contains 1 person.

Suppose that i only want to use these 2 models and do not want to re-train or modify anything on the dataset. How could i locate female person in a picture of Dataset A?

A possible solution that i think could work:

First use the first model to detect, that is to create bounding boxes around persons in the images.

Crop the bounding boxes into unique images. Feed those images to the second model to see if that person is Female/Male

However, this solution is slow in performance. So is there anyway that can festen this solution or perform this task in different ways?

Comment: I did the method you describe above, use yolo to detect object, crop the bbox and feed to the second network. Why don't you use the Yolo for gender classification as well? Therefore you won't need to run 2 deep learning model

Comment: If you do not want to retrain the model, then possibly no. The approach you described is the only viable option and will be slow.

Comment: @gameon67 could u describe the process more specifically. Do you get the output vector of yolo, cut the box and save into images? Then feed into the 2nd cnn?

Comment: @TotallyNew yes, the output vector will give you x,y,w,h coordinates. Cut the the image inside the box using opencv. Feed the cropped image to the 2nd cnn